# NSCoding and Bools Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8

For whatever reason my application crashes everytime it decodes my Bool value.  It didn't crash before I updated to Swift 3.  I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.  If I take out the Bool value my application runs fine without crashing.  [image]

Comment: But think. You are saying `as!`. That _means_ "crash". You cannot be surprised when Swift does exactly what you told it to do!

Comment: Woahhhhhhh dude never thought of like that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been changed for Swift 3. There are associated decode...() functions for various different types.

The correct syntax is now:

```
let myBool = aDecoder.decodeBool(forKey: PropertyKey.completedKey)
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out instead of telling me how stupid I am :)